# How can a matrix affect one vector but not the other in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathsf T$ be a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ . Let $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, and $\vec w$ be three vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ , as shown below. We are told that $\mathsf T (\vec v_1) = \vec v_1$ and $\mathsf T (\vec v_2) = 3\vec v_2$. On the same axes, sketch $\mathsf T (\vec w)$.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjBY2.png)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why $\vec v_1$ is not affected but $\vec v_2$ is. Can someone shed some light on this for me.

Comment: $Tv=\lambda v$ is an eigenvalue equation. Are you familiar with that? Can you express $w$ as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example: Consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

What's $A\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$? What's $A\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Now, your matrix is essentially the same, just with a shift of the coordinate system.

Comment: But the vectors in the graph have both a x and y component to them. So wouldn't the matrix have to affect $\vec v_1$ as well?

Comment: Yes, in the graph. That's what I meant with a shift of the coordinate system. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, they are a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and you can take any vector, write it as a linear combination of these two. Then $v_1$ has the coordninate vector $(1,0)^T$ and $v_2$ has the coordinate vector $(0,1)^T$.

Comment: @LaneFord: Do you agree that in my particular one vector isn't influenced when the other is, even if this matrix might be a special case?

Comment: oh now I see thank you.